# JNA: Enumerating system handles memory error -1073740940 (0xC0000374)

Tags: java, windows, pointers, winapi, jna

I am trying to enumerate over all system handles in Windows 64-bit with the following:

```
WinDef.ULONGByReference nBufferLength = new WinDef.ULONGByReference();
Memory pInfo = new Memory(4);
long ntStatus = -1;
while (ntStatus != 0 /* NT_SUCCESS */) {
    ntStatus = NtDll.INSTANCE.NtQuerySystemInformation(
                       0x10, pInfo, (int) pInfo.size(), nBufferLength);
    if (ntStatus == 0xC0000004 /*STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH*/) {
        if (pInfo != Pointer.NULL) {
            Native.free(Pointer.nativeValue(pInfo));
        }
        int bufferLength = nBufferLength.getValue().intValue();
        pInfo = new Memory(bufferLength);
    } else if (ntStatus != 0) {
        throw new Win32Exception(Native.getLastError());
    }
}

long handleCount = pInfo.getLong(0);
long handleAddress = Pointer.nativeValue(pInfo.share(8));
for (int i = 0; i < handleCount; i++) {
    SYSTEM_HANDLE currentHandle = new SYSTEM_HANDLE(new Pointer(handleAddress));
    System.out.println(handleAddress + "@" + currentHandle.ProcessId);

    lpHandle += currentHandle.size();
}
```

But during the loop I always run into exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374).

So, I saw the warning of the constructor `Pointer(long peer)`, and I, not knowing what I'm doing, tried to switch the code to use `share` instead of direct address manipulation. This is MASSIVELY slower and eventually stack overflows.

Here is my `SYSTEM_HANDLE` structure:

```
public class SYSTEM_HANDLE extends Structure {

    public WinDef.ULONG ProcessId;
    public WinDef.BYTE ObjectTypeNumber;
    public WinDef.BYTE Flags;
    public WinDef.USHORT Handle;
    public WinDef.PVOID Object;
    public WinDef.DWORD GrantedAccess;

    public SYSTEM_HANDLE(Pointer p) {
        super(p);
        read();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("ProcessId", "ObjectTypeNumber", "Flags", 
                             "Handle", "Object", "GrantedAccess");
    }

}
```

Comment: Does your loop do something with `i`?

Comment: @conio No, to terminate the loop it should reach `handleCount` which is typically 50000 to 100000.

Comment: Does the error occur immediately or after a while? After a few rounds or a thousand rounds? What is `lpHandle`?

Comment: @Jire: That's nice, but you always duplicate the same handle.